# call api response on getting in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux, es6-promise

I'm beginner in redux and ReactJs. I have issue with when i trying to call login api the response not getting.

```
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware';
export function login(toSend) {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(mopetsLogin(toSend)).then(() =>
        {
            console.log(getState().mopets_api.token.access_token);
            dispatch(mopetsMe(getState().mopets_api.token.access_token));
        });
    }
}

export function mopetsLogin(toSend) {
    console.log('toSend');
    console.log(toSend);
    return {
        [CALL_API]: {
            endpoint: 'http://api.mopets.com/app_dev.php/login',
            method: 'POST',
            /*headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },*/
            body: JSON.stringify(toSend),
            types: [
                'INITIAL_LOGIN_MOPETS_REQUEST',
                {
                    type: 'INITIAL_LOGIN_MOPETS_SUCCESS',
                    payload: (action, state, res) => {
                        const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type');
                        if (contentType && ~contentType.indexOf('json')) {
                            // Just making sure res.json() does not raise an error
                            const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type');
                            if (contentType && ~contentType.indexOf('json')) {
                                // Just making sure res.json() does not raise an error
                                return res.json().then((json) => {
                                        var o = new Object();
                                        o["token"] = json;
                                        return o;
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                            ;
                        }
                    }
                },
                'INITIAL_LOGIN_MOPETS_FAILURE'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

> main.bundle.js:42605 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined

this type error showing 
can please look the code and provide some information to solve this.

Comment: There are two `then` in your dispatch function.

Comment: i removed one but still having error @Thinker

Comment: `. then(loginResult => console.log(loginResult.token))`? Also don't use `new Object` use `return  {token: json};`

Comment: how?, i don't know about that @AluanHaddad

Comment: @PrakashSatani login method returns a promise for an object containing the token. So you need to pass a one param callback to `then`. The param refers to that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appens firs because your

```
getState().mopets_api.token
```

is undefined.

Maybe it is only a path problem, try to console.log your res to check if the object gets correctly populated.

Comment: i check console.log(getState().mopets_api, but this is showing null object
@user1234087